# django-rosetta not saving translations on hitting "Save and Translate next block" in Chrome

Tags: django, internationalization, django-admin, django-rosetta

`django-rosetta` is not saving the translations on hitting "Save and Translate next block" in Chrome.
It seems to be working fine in Firefox though. I tried clearing cache so that does not seem to be an issue.

On Chrome, after entering translated text and hitting the "Save.." button, I'm redirected to the main screen without my changes being saved.

I updated to the most recent version of rosetta thinking that the Issue13 fix would solve my problem but it does not.

I've also made sure that my .po and .mo files have 777 permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Been a long time, not sure if you were able to sort it out?

I have a dev environment running Django 1.4.2 and Rosetta 0.6.8 on Lion and it works flawlessly. Im setting it up with the `python manage.py runserver` command.

Then when I wanted to deploy it to my Ubuntu 12 server Rosetta started to behave quite weird. I installed Nginx as a proxy and was running apache with wsgi. Same versions besides that. It was not just the translated strings that were not being saved but the navigation became absolute random. Did not matter what button I pressed, I suspected the proxy configuration wasn´t setup properly since I could run it locally in my dev.

To make a long story short, I finally shutdown nginx and apache and just ran django with the builtin and hence got the django logs in my terminal. It got a lot of errors that made the server restart itself every few seconds. This obviously explained the somewhat non-reliable behavior of the app. I dumped the database in production and resynced it. Now when I `runserver` in production it works just as good as in my dev. When I plug in apache to do the job (going around nginx for the moment) the problem still persist, not as bad as before though. Browser does not make any difference.

One of the errors that did pop up was this

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of         <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x1781710>>
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 50, inapport_excepthook
    if not enabled():
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Still havent solved this but will be posting the solution when I do.

**EDIT:**
Scratched the good ol´ apache wsgi setup and went for Gunicorn instead. Works really well now, not sure what that was all about but I´m quite happy with the new setup anyways. 
Here´s a good setup guide

http://ijcdigital.com/blog/django-gunicorn-and-nginx-setup/

hopefully this helps someone in the future!

Comment: Found this bug on Rosettas Github. Seems like its a Caching issue. 
https://github.com/mbi/django-rosetta/issues/59